# Trouble using showing date on UILabel?

Tags: uilabel, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get a label to show the date in the format of (Month) XX, XXXX

Using:

```
    currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    date.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Unfortunately, the label text doesn't even change, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  first you have set IBOutlet connection date label

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM  YYYY"];
date.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate]
```